# xslt adds "ns0" with the namespace attribute with root element, how to avoid this?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using namespace attibute of xsl:element to put a namespace in the result XML.  It puts the namespace in there, but like this:

```
xmlns:ns0="http://...."
```

and puts <root> as <ns0:root>.  I want to put the namespace without "ns0".

Comment: Can you be more specific, as to which XSLT processor you use, how exactly your code looks (XML and XSLT, desired output and current output)?

Comment: XSLT 

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:element name="myroot" namespace="http://xmlns.mynamespace.com/import">
                <xsl:attribute name="version">
                    <xsl:text>2.0</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>




this results in:

<ns0:myroot xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.mynamespaces.com/import" version="2.0" />


the xslt processor i am using is i think Xalan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:element name="myroot" namespace="xmlns.mynamespace.com/import">;
>   <xsl:attribute name="version">
>     <xsl:text>2.0</xsl:text>
>   </xsl:attribute>
>   <xsl:apply-templates />
> </xsl:element>
> ```

**Simply re-write this as**:

```
<myroot xmlns="xmlns.mynamespace.com/import" version="2.0">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</myroot>
```